# pod setup fail at 'Setting up CocoaPods master repo'

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to install cocoapods and it always fail at 'Setting up CocoaPods master repo' with below error code:

```
[!] /usr/bin/git clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master --depth=1 
sh: line 1:  8018 Abort trap: 6           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find git 2> /dev/null
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

I've tried all the suggestions on StackOverFlow like uninstall and re-install cocoapods or rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master but it still fail.
I'm using xCode 6.1.1 with the newest Command Line Tool on Yosemite 10.10

Comment: Do you have "git" installed on your machine? Type "git" in terminal and see if it works? Also try "which git" to see the path installation for git.

Comment: @gagarwal When I type "git" in terminal it gave me the same error as in the question sh: line 1:   842 Abort trap: 6           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find git 2> /dev/null
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH

But when I try "which git" it gave me the path: /usr/bin/git

Comment: Try running "xcode-select --install" to fix the developer tools.

Comment: I'm in the very same  case than OP and "sudo xcode-select --install" tells me: "xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates".
Apparently no fix was applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days going crazy with it. I found a workaround to resolve this problem. It's a workaround because I don't know the root cause and I have to repeat these steps every time I want to do command relates with cocoapods.

Seems like the PATH variable for cocoapods has been changed in Yosemite 10.10, so you need to fix the PATH for cocoapods to understand it.

First, I have to use this command:

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

Then this:

```
pod setup
```

And this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

After that, I could use 'pod setup', 'pod install', 'pod search',... normally as I did before.

Does anybody know how to completely resolve this problem? Because everytime I want to update the pods, I have to repeat those steps above

Comment: After doing the "rm -rf" part (That folder didn't exist in my case), "pod setup" just yields the same git error.

Comment: @Isaac I think that means the folder is already removed. You could skip that command and try the next two commands to see if it works.

Comment: As I said before, after the "rm -rf" part (which I just typed because I wanted to be strict with the described procedure, at that time I already knew that folder didn't exist in the first place), I launched "pod setup" and readjusted my PATH environement variable, but no luck. Finally I just had to reinstall git from github, overriding osx/xcode (?) one, and readjusted my PATH accordingly. Since then "everything seems ok", but I feel a bit meh as it was an emergency fix and not a proper solution... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by running in term:

```
gem update
pod install
```